# Is SQL Server Compact Edition a sensible alternative to SQLite?

Tags: .net, sqlite, sql-server-ce

What are the differences, other than a file size restriction in SQL Server Compact, and Windows only usage?

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative?  Whether SQL Server Compact Edition is a sensible alternative depends on your answer.  In our case, it certainly is not a sensible alternative, but our requirements are certainly different from yours.

Comment: @Sam: In a Microsoft-only shop, it is problematic to introduce open-source software that doesn't have Microsoft's blessing, especially when there is a potentially viable alternative available from Microsoft.

Comment: agreed, if your requirement is "use MS whenever possible" then that changes the arguments for SQL Server Compact Edition vs SQLite.

Comment: Unfortunately MS EULA's prevent publishing performance statistics without permission so you won't find many performance analysis out there, but you should do your own comparisons with your types of data so you know how big the difference is.  In our situation, we were very surprised at the results.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278104/sql-ce-sqlite-what-are-the-differences-between-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278104/sql-ce-sqlite-what-are-the-differences-between-them) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127/database-functionality-with-wpf-app-sqlite-sql-ce-other) and some [blog](http://ayende.com/blog/2007/01/27/fromsqlitetosqlservercompactedition.aspx) [posts](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/22/SQLite-vs.-SQL-CE.aspx) relating to this. A small comparison of their memory usage can be found [here](http://dotnetperls.com/sqlite-versus-sqlce).