# SQLite or SQL Server Compact for .NET project

Tags: c#, .net, database, vb.net

I need a simple embedded database for a relatively small database size (< 100MB, but in most cases < 20MB) and maximum 1-2 concurrent users/connections on average. It must be able to protect/encrypt it's data with a login.

Which database is best for the job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is SQL Server Compact Edition a sensible alternative to SQLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301370/is-sql-server-compact-edition-a-sensible-alternative-to-sqlite)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### SQLite

**Pros**
- Supports in-memory database
- Good performance
- Real XCopy installation (or real embedding)
- Open source and platform independent
- Has C# porting -> http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

**Cons**
- C API (low productive)
- Poor SQL support
- Could be very complicated with large data set
- No direct support of data encryption (extensions available)

### SQL CE

**Pros**
- Good query analyzer (ordinary queries can be shared with SQL Server)
- Plenty of information, good documentation (short learning time)
- Support OLE DB (C/C++) and ADO.NET
- Native support of Data encryption
- Support SQL Replication (really cool feature)

**Cons**
- No XCopy installation (could interfere with another install)
- Well.. that's all?

For your scenario, definitely SQL CE, isn't it?

Comment: How difficult is the installation? Isn't it just copying DLLs; that's what I'm thinking when reading "embedded".

Comment: Regarding SQLite: There's an ADO.NET provider, which would make it quite easy, or not (don't have any experience with it yet)?. Link: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/.

Comment: That is the provider I was referring to. It's good, though I've only used it in single-user mode where I didn't have to worry about multiple writers stepping on each other's toes.

Comment: @Marc V Basically DLL copy install is possible with SQL CE. But there are prerequisites, starting from .NET framework, MDAC, etc. So normally one would run separate setup.exe for SQL CE.

Comment: @Tim Wow! Haven't thought of that is possible! "Sources are in the public domain. Use for any purpose." Really cool, isn't it? I bookmarked this Q/A only to remember your comment. Thanks!

Comment: SQL CE 4 supports Xcopy - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/sql-server-compact-private-deployment.html - but no direct access across a LAN

Comment: I'm almost certainly going to use SQLite with the Devart dotConnector. So far this works great.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption is not free in SQLite.

But it is very easy to embed with its non-invasive footprint and simple file copy install.

SQLite provider for .NET is robust (at least in single-user mode--I've never created a multiple-concurrent-writers app using SQLite and probably never would because SQLite uses a file-locking scheme not a record-locking scheme and all my apps tend to have only one user or many users. So you'd have to spend time handling concurrency issues.

Also, SQLite has quite good SQL support and it handles large datasets well.

So you need to assign a priority weight to each of your requirements.  How important is ease-of-install? How important is concurrency? How important is encryption?

Comment: On "http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com" I've read that they support encryption; or am I missing some information?

Comment: @Marc V: difficult to say from the brief blurb "entire database can be encrypted". I know that SQLite has a (paid) encryption-capable version, but I've never used it, nor have I looked into the .NET provider's encryption approach.  I don't know how it works, or how well it performs witn concurrent writers and large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

They should both handle the job equally well.

If you're familiar with SQL Server development, SQL Server Compact Edition will probably give you the least number of headaches. The provider, queries, and connection string will be familiar.

Comment: I know SQL Server quite well (done a lot with it), but am not afraid to use something else. The only thing that matters is which one is the best choice (most lightweighted; fastest; secure ...).

Comment: @Marc V - My point is that if you know SQL Server CE, that is the best choice. You'll have less issues, write better code, and end up with a better product. Your users aren't going to notice the difference between the two.

Comment: @Marc V: SQLite without the paid encryption version is not secure but it is fast and lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

They are both great IMO. But, whenever possible, I try to stick with MS stuff when working in .NET. This assumes that the budget is in place to do so... but since you're looking at SQL Server CE and Sqlite they are both free. Both will support the EF but I would assume that Sql Server CE will have better support in most areas.

Also, have you considered looking at db4o for an embedded solution? Pretty nice NoSQL solution... and it's also free.

Comment: Right point. Go with MS stuff when in .NET. Also you will be able to scale it to SQL server if needed. But then SQLLite is open-source, advantage over paying license fee for SQL CE.

Comment: For this solution I don't need large storage, so CE would be fine. It must be free/cheap, small and have "almost zero" installation problems.