# SQL Server Compact 4.0 vs. SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-ce

I'm interested in choosing an embedded DB engine for my WPF app. I would like information on how SQLite and latest SQL CE 4.0 compare. And if I should choose one over the other. Points of interest would be ORM support with EF4's CTP & NHibernate 3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database functionality with WPF app: SQLite, SQL CE, other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127/database-functionality-with-wpf-app-sqlite-sql-ce-other)

Comment: Sqlite now works with EF and Linq to SQL, and there is a nuget package that supports migrations.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See this answer: [Database functionality with WPF app: SQLite, SQL CE, other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127/database-functionality-with-wpf-app-sqlite-sql-ce-other) 
- SQL Compact 4 has full support for Entity Framework, Linq to SQL
- Includes all neccesary file for private deployment
- has good tools support in Visual Studio 2010 and 2012
- has a smooth migration path to SQL Server

Comment: That answer doesn't really apply to SQL CE 4.0. as SQL CE 4.0 now has almost all of the benefits that answers mentioned about SQLite.

Comment: SQL Compact 4 isn't fully supported in all version of visual studio. Try using it with c# under visual studio express.

Comment: Broken link on the referred answer.

Comment: Link to answer is bad

Comment: Sqlite now works with EF and Linq to SQL, and there is a nuget package that supports migrations.