# Embedded databases: SQLite or SQL CE?

Tags: .net, sql, database

I currently trying to decide which embedded database to pick up for new .NET project. There are 2 candidates: SQLite and SQL CE.

I put the performance on first place. But it is also important, are there support for microORM tools like Dapper-dot-net or Simple.Data.

If you tried both and have opinion on that, I would be happy to hear!

Comment: or maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839342/sql-server-compact-4-0-vs-sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only advantage in .NET for SQL CE i can think of is the ability to integrate it on the designer.

On the other hand, in regard to speed, SQL standard compliance and memory usage, I would strongly recommend that you use SQLite.

Don't get me wrong, I believe SQL CE is a wonderful database, but also bear in mind that SQLite is compiled in one DLL file, and can be used in any .Net product.

Comment: Actually, SQLite supports the query designer in VS2008. http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/readme.htm

Comment: //in regard to speed, SQL standard compliance ..., I would strongly recommend that you use SQLite.// reference needed

Answer (score 2):

I've used both*, and when you say "performance" is your primary concern, you need to be a bit more specific.

For example, executing many inserts/updates in SQLite is quite a bit slower, unless you wrap them all in a single transaction and commit at the end.  SQL CE's query syntax is somewhat simplier, meaning I had to execute multiple commands and merge / manipulate data in code.

Given the wide variety of use cases for "performance" (latency, queries / second, rows / second, even code or DB size), I suggest you wire up a harness and do some hands-on testing.  I did the same a while back in our comparison, but in the end realized we were better served using the SQLite callbacks to do some manipulation.

SQL CE 3.5 and SQLite.Net, so I wasn't using the latest, or I was using a proxy wrapper which adds a smidgeon of overhead.