# Offline application - database

Tags: c#, sql, database, desktop-application, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a problem with in choosing a database for desktop applications.
The application will work offline, and require a relational database.

My first idea was to create a strong typed dataset and keeping data in xml. But this is not a safe option.

The second idea is to place the SQL Express on computer, but it will be a exhausting.

Which option should I use? Maybe you have other ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with SQLite?

Comment: Or, what's wrong with SQL Server Compact?

Comment: Nothing wrong with Express either, for that matter. SQLite, Compact, Express- all viable options. But you need to define 'safe'. Depending on what you mean, arguably none of them is safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) with SQLite-NET or [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx) for an offline database.

Quick edit: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278104/sql-ce-sqlite-what-are-the-differences-between-them) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839342/sql-server-compact-4-0-vs-sqlite) is a comparison of SQL Server CE vs SQLite.

Comment: Ill use SQL Server CE.
"has good tools support in Visual Studio 2010 - has a smooth migration path to SQL Server" Thank you

Comment: @VoonArt No problem. SQL Server CE is stripped down version of SQL Server, so it *probably* has better integration. On the other hand, SQLite is the only embedded DB that works in WinRT apps - and that's where I used it. Anyway, I'm glad you made up your mind and that I could point you in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use standard *.mdf in-file-database with EF using LINQ. Client won't need anything other than .NET installed on his machine.