# Creating a Local DB for a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite

I have an application and I want to create a DB in the same folder as the application. I looked into SQLite for .NET 4.0 everything looked fine untill I got an exception             "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.88.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." The SQLite works with a console .NET application. I dont want to use SQL Server at all. Is there an alternative other than XML files?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839342/sql-server-compact-4-0-vs-sqlite) has some good guidance for the same scenario

Comment: You can try many things cleaning and rebuilding the solution , restarting the IDE , sometimes some process uses that specific DLL so ending that process. It's simply some build issue so no need to migrate to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one more solution to this issue. The problem was with the platform (x86/x64). I got the source code of Sqllite v1.0.88 and opened the VS 2010 solution file. I noticed that the target was mixed platforms by default. I changed it to any CPU and built the System.Data.SQLite.2010 project. I referenced this dll in my project and I did not have an issue with x86/x64 platform. One dll worked for both.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite is a great choice for the scenario you describe. Giving up on SQLite because you could not include it correctly seems like the wrong conclusion. Reference it through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/1.0.88.0) and you are fine. The library needs `SQLite.Interop.dll` which you might not have included correctly. You might also have included something like the x64 version when you are running under x86 (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503634/64-bit-sqlite-dll-and-any-cpu) for details). Use it through NuGet and you should be OK.

Here is the quick setup I got working in under 5 minutes:

1. Created console application (VS Express 2012 for Desktop, .NET v4, Any CPU, Debug)
2. Installed via NuGet
3. Used the following code
4. Works like a charm!

Code sample:

```
string dataSource = "SQLiteDemo.db";
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + dataSource;
connection.Open();
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS beispiel ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO beispiel (id, name) VALUES(NULL, 'Test-Datensatz!')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Dispose();
connection.Dispose();
```

Comment: I tried referencing it through NuGet and still got the same issue. Im using VS 2010 and targeting Any CPU,.NET 4.0 and I also open the same solution in VS 2012 as well

Comment: When I create a console app it works fine for me as well.But doesn't work with a wpf app referencing the same dll

Comment: You need to provide more specifics to get help for your scenario. It has nothing to do with the app being a WPF or console app. It has most certainly something to do with your build configuration and your referencing libraries.

Comment: Try the same thing with a blank wpf app. You are most likely to get an exception ie BadImageFileExeption. My machine that im developing is a 64 bit and my app target platform is any cpu.So I installed the 32bit dll is that a oroblem? If I do install the 64 bit dll will it work on 32 bit machines?

Comment: You were right, I created another sample WPF app and the sql lite DB works fine. What could I be missing? This is the exception I get Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.88.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: My guess is: Wrong native SQLite DLL for the build configuration used. Have you double-checked your build configuration for the whole solution and all the projects?

Comment: My app builds with the config Any CPU in VS 10

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503634/64-bit-sqlite-dll-and-any-cpu. You have a 64-bit OS and therefore you probably need the 64-bit DLL. 32-bit systems need the 32-bit DLL.

Comment: Its finally working. Thanx a lot!! But this 64 bit dll would not work on 32 bit machines rite? So I gotta keep both the dll's?

Comment: Correct, unfortunately.